# Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:5432

Tags: docker

He tratado de ejecutar el docker-compose pero obtengo errores de conexión a la base de datos (de forma local funciona)
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No sé cual podría ser el error ya que he modificado el codigo y sigue el error.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Archivo docker-compose

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hola @BDamaris cómo estas?
Veo 2 errores en tu ejercicio.

Mira el primer error que puedo ver es que si tu estás contenerizando una aplicación sea cual sea la tecnología, debes tener presente que una cosa es la red de docker y otra cosa la comunicación entre un servicio, en tu caso en el servicio del docker compose donde defines la BD se accede desde tu equipo host así: localhost:5432 o 127.0.0.1:5432.

Sin embargo desde otro contenedor lo debes llamar o bien asignando una ip privada fija en el docker, lo cual no recomiendo o simplemente llamando el nombre de servicio o nombre del contenedor, es decir así:
inventario-postgres:5432.

```
  @Module({
  imports: [
    TypeOrmModule.forRoot({
      type: 'postgres',
      host: 'inventario-postgres',
      port: 5432,
      username: 'user1',
      password: 'pass1',
      database: 'user1',
      synchronize: true,
      entities: ['src/**/*.entity{.ts,.js}'],
      migrations: ['./src/migrations/*.ts'],
    }),
    TypeOrmModule.forRoot({
      type: 'postgres',
      name: 'read',
      host: '127.0.0.2',
      port: 5432,
      username: 'user2',
      password: 'pass2',
      database: 'user2',
      entities: ['src/**/*.entity{.ts,.js}'],
     migrations: ['./src/migrations/*.ts'],
   })
  ],
  controllers: [HealthCheckController],
  providers: [],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

El segundo error que veo es que, si ya tienes un docker-compose.yml es mejor que siempre ejecutes los contenedores de forma unida con el comando:

```
docker-compose up
```

puedes usar -d para que no te bloquee la pantalla aunque te recomiendo que inicialmente no lo uses para que puedas ver los logs de ambos contenedores.

En lo personal siempre cambio el puerto de salida para el host y el host interno para no confundirme, de igual manera siempre uso el mismo nombre de servicio y el nombre de contenedor. Finalmente para que no haya problemas con otros proyectos le incluyo un red propia a cada docker compose, mira el siguiente ejemplo:

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  # servicio 1: La base de datos
  serv-mariadb:
    image: mariadb:10.3
    container_name: serv-mariadb
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_DATABASE: root
      MYSQL_USER: root
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: 1234
    ports:
      - 33069:3306
    volumes:
      - ./MariaDB/schemas:/var/lib/mysql
    networks:
      - red_proyecto  
  # servicio 2: La instalación de apache
  serv-administrador:
    image: miusuario/phpoci8:7.2-mac
    container_name: serv-administrador
    restart: always    
    volumes:
      - ./modadministrador:/var/www/html
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    networks:
      - red_proyecto      
    # depends_on indica que se cree primero la bd (servicio 1)
    depends_on:
      - serv-mariadb
# se confirman los volumenes
volumes:
  MariaDB:
networks:
  red_proyecto:
    name: red_proyecto
```

Y luego en la configuración del proyecto, en este caso laravel, la conexión referencia al nombre del contenedor y no a localhost:

```
APP_NAME=miproyecto
APP_ENV=desarrollo
APP_KEY=base64:BhRDnK+l2tgTkPQmvKeZ3wbcfwg5sSDnKOho89nsHASH=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_LOG_LEVEL=debug
APP_URL=http://localhost
APP_URL_DOMINIO=https://miproyecto.com

DB_CONNECTION=baseadmin
DB_HOST=serv-mariadb 
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=dev_mods_admin
DB_USERNAME=root 
DB_PASSWORD=root
```

Espero te sea de ayuda.